# Why is my set timeout not functioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with the timer function not working can anyone poit out why this might be the case? Im sure this is something simple but just not sure what it is.

```
<a class="item"></a>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>

.item {width:50px; height:50px; background:red; margin:10px; float:left; opacity:1; }


$("document").ready(function() {
    var tooltipTimeout;

    $(".item").hover(function () {
    tooltipTimeout = setTimeout( $(".item").not(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.5), 2000);
    },
    function () {
        $(".item").stop().fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });


});
```

Thanks.

see http://jsfiddle.net/Jrand/wqJMt/1/

Comment: You're not passing a function to `setTimeout`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the JS to be executed in an anonymous function. Also, `setTimeout()` will change the value of `this` (explanation on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem)), so make sure you assign `this` to a new variable within your `hover()` function, and use that as your `.not()` argument instead:

```
$(".item").hover(function () {
  var item = this;
  tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(function() { $(".item").not(item).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.5) }, 2000);
},
function () {
    $(".item").stop().fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/wqJMt/5/).